# Unable to paginate a custom page query

Tags: wp-query, pages, pagination, templates, query

I have this code on a page called **Categories**.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Categories
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    Categories
                </h1>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php   

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => '4',
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'categories' );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have set the template in admin to **page-categories**

The pagination shows up with the correct number of pages to browse, however, when I click on the next page (the link is something like `example.com/categories/page/2/` ) I get 404 page.

Why is that? how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the same name for category slug "categories" and the same for the custom page that was holding all categories with the same name "categories".

I have solved that by changing categories slug (in permalinks settings) to singular "category" and I have left custom page as plural "categories".

If somebody know about some better solution, please let me know, thanks.

P.S. I was thinking about deleting this question, however, I think thinks is an interesting problem and maybe somebody will find it helpful. But If any moderator think it's ot worth of sharing, you can delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
```

Should be set to the $paged var you just set, like so:

```
            'paged' => $paged
```